# Android Kotlin - Issue to suppress safeUnbox warning for two-way binding values

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

Experts,

I'm trying to suppress a safeUnbox warning for a two-way bound property (Android/Kotlin). To do this, I created a singleton with custom unbox functions for the different data types (see below).

My build fails with the error below. It may be due to the fact that Kotlin uses kotlin.Boolean as the data type for the 'checked' variable and the Binding functionality uses java.lang.Boolean.

Any suggestions how I can resolve the issue greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Error Message:
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method unbox(java.lang.Boolean) in class com.example.ui.bindingAdapters.InverseSafeUnboxBindingAdapter

ViewModel definition:

```
var checked = MutableLiveData(false)
```

card_example.xml:

```
            <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="@={com.example.ui.bindingAdapters.InverseSafeUnboxBindingAdapter.unbox(vm.checked)}"/>
```

Binding Adapter:

```
package com.example.ui.bindingAdapters

import androidx.databinding.InverseMethod


object InverseSafeUnboxBindingAdapter {
    @InverseMethod("boxBoolean")
    fun unbox(b: Boolean?): Boolean {
        return b as Boolean
    }

    fun boxBoolean(b: Boolean): Boolean? {
        return b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find a working solution to work around this issue. The trick is to create the code that implements the unbox and inverse function as a Java file, not Kotlin.

I created a Java file with the code as shown below and was able to use it in the xml file along with two-way bound variables.

```
import androidx.databinding.InverseMethod;

public class CustomSafeUnboxAdapter {
    @InverseMethod("boxBoolean")
    public static boolean unbox(Boolean boxed) {
        return (boxed != null) && boxed.booleanValue();
    }

    public static Boolean boxBoolean(boolean unboxed) {
        return unboxed ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```